# Have any speculative answers from this site been used in any subsequent official works? If so, what was the first instance?

Tags: inspiration

On this site, there are questions that are often not directly answered by anything in canon materials. Sometimes answers need to be speculative. My question is, **have there been any *speculative accepted* answers (based on the best available evidence at the time) that have been used in subsequent official (i.e. not fan-fiction) works**?  If so, **what was the first instance of this?**

I know this might be a bit opinion based, so I'll constrain it to *any instances where this site has been specifically acknowledged or contacted regarding this*.

Comment: Based on the [positive meta response](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/7164/is-this-question-on-topic) to this question being on topic, it will now remain open, **regardless of any future VTC**.

Comment: [snip] Please restrict future comments to those relating to the question itself, not whether it's on-(or off-)topic.

Comment: Presumed answer: Not on your lifetime. Nobody wants to get sued for plagiarism or lose a % of revenues. That's a reason many writers explicitly refuse to read fanfics.

Comment: Not quite what the question is asking for, but just a few minutes ago I was watching *Rick and Morty* on *Adult Swim*, and in one of the bumps between commercials, they mentioned our own beloved mod, Thaddeus, and a calculation he is responsible for which explains how much money Bruce Wayne spent to become Batman.  Thaddeus has an answer about that on this site, so the bump may have been an indirect reference to this very site.